# C++ program wont compile with expected expression and function not allowed here

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


const int lab8 = 10;
int labArray[lab8];
void promptUser(int [], int);
void sortArray(int [], int);
void showArray(const int[], int);
int searchArray(const int [], int, int value);
int x = 0;
int results = 0;

int main()
{

promptUser(labArray, lab8);
sortArray(labArray, lab8);
showArray(labArray, lab8);
cout << "Choose an integer you want to search from the array: " << endl;
cin >> x;
results = searchArray(labArray, lab8, x);
if (results == -1) {
    cout << "That number does not exist in the array. \n";
    else
    {
        cout << "The integer you searched for was for at element " <<  results;
        cout << " in the array. \n";
    }


}

 void promptUser(int numbers[], int size)
{
int index;
for (index = 0; index <= size - 1;index++ )
{
    cout << "Please enter ten numbers to fill the array " << endl
         << (index + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> numbers[index];
}

}
void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
bool swap;
int temp;

do
{
    swap = false;
    for (int count = 0; count < (size -1); count++)
    {
        if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
        {
            temp = array[count];
            array[count] = array[count + 1];
            array[count + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
} while (swap);
}
void showArray(const int array[], int size)
{
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
{
    cout << "The array you entered when sorted was: ";
    cout << array[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
}

int searchArray(const int array[], int size, int value)
{
int first = 0,
last = size - 1,
middle,
position = - 1;
bool found = false;

while (!found && first <= last)
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (array[middle] == value)
    {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
    }
    else if (array[middle] > value)
        last = middle - 1;
    else
        first = middle + 1;
}

return position;
}
```

I am new to c++ and just working on an assignment for my class. I thought the program I wrote would have worked but for the life of me I can not figure out why it will not compile. I am sure I am missing something or not understanding how it should work completely. The errors I keep receiving are expected expression on line 26 by the 'else' statement and when I put the 'if' and 'else' statements in I started receiving function not allowed here errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the if statement, you open the bracket { but you never close it. Not sure if this is the problem but it should raise some issues.

```
    if (results == -1) {
    cout << "That number does not exist in the array. \n";
     **}**
    else
    {
        cout << "The integer you searched for was for at element " <<  results;
        cout << " in the array. \n";
    }
```

This is how it should look. Try it